# Creating association with State, Province, District and City with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, model, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Please make me help, This my first question in Ruby on Rails

My application have 4 model State, province, district & city.

```
app/models/state.rb
 Class State < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :provinces
end

app/models/province.rb
 Class Province < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :state
 has_many :districts
end

app/models/district.rb
Class District < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :province
 has_many :cities
end

app/models/city.rb
 Class City < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :district
end
```

My schema.rb i added foreign Key to table.

My question are?

How show link like this ***domain.com/state/2/province/4/district/6/city/4*** ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally not a good practice to nest resources more than 2 levels deep.

But if you really want to do it, add this to routes.

```
resources :states do
  resources :provinces do
    resources :districts do
      resources :cities
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can use the path helper

```
state_province_district_city_path(@state, @province, @district, @city)
```

This will give `/state/2/province/4/district/6/city/4` if

```
@state.id # => 2
@province.id # => 4
@district.id # => 6
@city.id # => 4
```

Comment: what mean 2 levels deep? any other way solution you have?

Comment: How to display all province under state?

Comment: Two level `/state/2/province/4`. Three level `/state/2/province/4/district/6`

Comment: If you have `State` object, say `@state`. You can call `@state.provinces`, which will give you all the provinces of the state

Comment: I have news model, news belongs_to city & city have many news... what is code for - how many news amount (count) in city?

Comment: You could do `@city.news.count` Please have a look at  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html to know more about model associations.

Comment: I have another question.. i Create CRUD for state,province,district and city. First i create list of state, then i am creating province, in here when i am create province how to child of state? what i am want put in state controller?

Comment: Please post it as a separate question with specific details of the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Add your controller state

```
@state = State.new
@state.province_id = (params[:province_id])
```